# Vue not setting <select> value by v-model in IE

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This seems to work in Chrome, but not IE. Do you have any ideas why?

```
<select v-model="selected">
   <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{ option.foo }}</option>
</select>
```

```
var data = [{ foo: 1 }, { foo: 2 }]

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        selected: null,
        options: data
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.selected = data[1]
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3267/

Related ticket: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a timing bug. With a `setTimeout`, I was able to get it to work, though using `$nextTick` did *not* fix it.

```
  mounted: function() {
    setTimeout(function () { demo.selected = data[1]; }, 0);
  }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/205oy8xf/)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that a timeout could solve it. Was hoping for an alternative :)

Comment: I'm accepting this. Let's hope that it gets patched. Added the relevant github ticket